# How to use bootstrap 4 in angular 2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular, npm, sass

I'm building an angular 2 app written in typescript. It would use the bootstrap 4 framework in combination with some custom theming, is this possible?

The "ng2-bootstrap" npm package is not working as it doesn't allow me to use the bootstrap css classes, instead it provides custom components. (http://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap)

In my angular 2 project I'm using sass, would it be possible to build bootstrap 4 from source as it is also using sass for styling?

Comment: you can use it normal way. I'm not sure about your sass. `ng2-bootstrap` only provides you components.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Bootstrap4 alpha for Angular2 CLI (also works for Angular4 CLI)**

If you are using the **angular2 cli/angular 4 cli** do following:

```
npm i bootstrap@next --save
```

This will add bootstrap 4 to your project.

Next go to your `src/style.scss` or `src/style.css` file and import bootstrap there:

**For style.css**

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

**For style.scss**

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

If you are using scss, make sure you change your default styling to scss in `.angular-cli.json`:

```
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
```

**Bootstrap JS Components**

For Bootstrap JS components to work you will still need to import `bootstrap.js` into `.angular-cli.json` under `scripts` *(this should happen automatically)*:

```
...     
"scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                  "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
                  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"],
...
```

**Update 2017/09/13:** *Boostrap 4 Beta is now using popper.js instead of tether.js. So depending on which version you are using import either tether.js (alpha) or popper.js (beta) in your scripts.* Thanks for the heads up @MinorThreat

Comment: This worked for me, but I also need to add the import statement to each component that needs it. E.g when I just add it to my styles.scss, my navbar component didn't look right until I also imported it into my navbar.component.scss file. This feels like a bit of an overhead as my application grows, having to import bootstrap into every component style sheet.

Comment: @MattSugden You should not need to import it into all components. Did you change your default style type to scss? See my updated answer!

Comment: @MattSugden  Also note, there was a recent update of bootstrap 4 which changed navigation style significantly. So check if you are using the right html elements and classes. I had similar problems with a project.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it was my mistake, I was adding it to app.component.scss, not styles.scss. It was late & I'd been looking at it for too long!

Comment: CSS-related stuff worked like a charm, but the js-libraries are not automatically added to the scripts array. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: @V.Lichtenberg not sure. What version are you using? Maybe you also need to add it manually ...

Comment: I think this posting should be updated. For example, I've noticed that they dropped tether in favor of popper.

Comment: @MinorThreat Bootstrap 4 is still using tether on their documentation https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @MinorThreat ok on the beta site they switched it ... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 40):

The options above will work, however I use this approach via NPM:

1. Navigate to: [Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#package-managers) and retrieve the npm command
2. Run the NPM command obtained from step 1 in your project i.e

   `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5 --save`
3. After installing the above dependency run the following npm command which will install the bootstrap module 
   `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` 
   You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap)
4. Add the following import into app.module `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` and add `NgbModule` to the `imports`
5. Your app module will look like this:

   ```
   import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

   @NgModule({
      declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      WeatherComponent
   ],
     imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     FormsModule,
     HttpModule,
     NgbModule.forRoot(), // Add Bootstrap module here.
   ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })

   export class AppModule { }
   ```
6. Open angular-cli.json and insert a new entry into the styles array :

   ```
   "styles": [
     "styles.css",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   ],
   ```
7. Open src/app/app.component.html and add

   ```
   <alert type="success">hello</alert>
   ```

   or if you would like to use ng alert then place the following on your `app.component.html page`

   ```
   <ngb-alert [dismissible]="true">I'm a dismissible alert :) </ngb-alert>
   ```
8. Now run your project and you should see the bootstrap alert message in the browser.

**NOTE: You can read more about [ng Components here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion)**

Comment: I could only get this to work by adding the import `NgbModule.forRoot()` (in line with the getting started guide) and using the tag <ngb-alert type="success" >hello</ngb-alert>. This displays the alert  (although I cannot close it).

Comment: @AlanHay have you looked at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert   - Closeable Alert ?

Comment: Try this: <ngb-alert [dismissible]="true">
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
  </ngb-alert>

Comment: I confirm that even adding `[dismissible]="true"` is not helping dismiss the alert. No matter how many times the X icon is clicked, the alert is not dismissed. There are no errors logged in console either.

Comment: Interesting, you'll need to use the `typescript` component code which is used in the example.

Comment: Nope the dismiss is not working. Check also their plunkr.

Comment: You need to implement the (close) event to dismiss the alert, as explained in the examples:
`<ngb-alert *ngIf="successMessage" type="success" (close)="successMessage = null">{{ successMessage }}</ngb-alert>`

Answer (score 11):

To use any visual library that needs JQuery just do the following:

- Add the library css in the index;
- Add the jquery js file to index;
- Add the library js files in the index;
- Install the library definition files (d.ts);
- Install jquery definitions files (d.ts);

If the library doesn't have definition files you could:

- Create the definition yourself;
- Create a global any variable with the same name of the library object, just to not get compiler errors;
- Use with errors (**this is the worst option**);

Now you can use the library inside Typescript;

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest:

- Simply including a link to the [Bootstrap's CSS file](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) in your `index.html` page
- Using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) - a dedicated set of Angular 2 directives for parts where dynamic behaviour is needed. This way you don't need to import / setup jQuery nor care about Bootstrap's JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You can use npm for installing the latest bootstrap version. This can be done using the command:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
```

And after this you might have to import bootstrap.css into your main css file. Which will be styles.css, if you are using angular-cli.

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

If you want to know more please use the link: http://technobytz.com/install-bootstrap-4-using-npm.html

Answer (score 1):

First goto your project directory and follow the below given steps.

1)   `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` (run this command in node js command prompt)

2)`npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6` (next run this)

3)`import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'`(write this in app module.ts)

4) If Module is your root module include this

```
`@NgModule({
 declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
 imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})`

    (or)
```

If not root Module

```
`@NgModule({
 declarations: [OtherComponent, ...],
 imports: [NgbModule, ...]
})`
```

5) Write this in system.config.js

```
`map: {
'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-
bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
}`
```

6) Add in Index.html

```
`<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`
```

Comment: Shouldn't the bootstrap 4 itself contain `--save`?

Answer (score 0):

In angular 6 dont use npm i bootstrap@next --save may it would work but sometimes it would not better to add these:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @ChrisEenberg now its ok??

Answer (score 0):

`ng add` has been introduced with Angular 6. To install [Bootstrap 4 (ng-bootstrap 2.0.0)](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/schematics
```

Don't forget to restart your app with `ng serve`.

Answer (score 0):

In angular 6: First install bootstrap in project directory `npm install bootstrap`. If you look at the Angular.JSON file you will see that styles.css is already referenced so in styles.css just add `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`

Answer (score 0):

> Angular v6 Onwards Bootstrap v4 and SCSS

This works fine with angular 7 scss enabled project

Run following commands for installing bootstrap, jQuery, and popper.js

```
npm install --save bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

jQuery, and popper.js are prerequisites for running bootstrap4 (refer https://getbootstrap.com for more information.)

Go to your angular.json file inside root folder. Edit

> architect -> build -> options -> scripts

node as follows

```
 "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

This will enable javascript functions of bootstrap on your project.

Than go to `src->styles.scss` file and add following line

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Bootstrap using Angular CLI:

```
step 1. npm i bootstrap@latest --save 
step 2. open angular.json and then add bootstrap:
 "styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "src/styles.scss"
    ]
step 3. restart the server to see the changes
        ng serve
```