# Best framework to multi-window app using electron.js

Tags: javascript, frameworks, electron

I wrote electron.js multi-window application using native javascript. I want to rewrite this app using one of javascript framework like React, Vue or Angular. They are SPA frameworks so I predict, that one instance corresponds to one window. I think that Angular may be too large for smaller windows. 
My app currently has one main window (that executes a lot of code) and three smaller, so I don't want to use too big frameworks for them. One more question: all of those framewoks are compatybile with typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built a multi-window (multi-page) Electron app using both Bootstrap and Angular and had no issues.

You can get Typescript definitions for React / Bootstrap [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap-typescript) or (for Bootstrap) [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap).

A tutorial for using Typescript with Angular can be found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-angular-2-using-typescript/).  It is a little dated but should be a good starting point.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534276/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-in-angular-2) in stackoverflow also has some useful information that you may find helpful.

Comment: But if I want to create more windows (not as SPA pages), that I need to bootstrap each window separately by angular framework, right (4 windows = 4 angular instances)? This is not too inefficient for the system?

Comment: @GoldenChris You can have Electron bring up your main Bootstrap window and then all other windows can be managed via the main Bootstrap window.

Comment: @GoldenChris Any luck with your issue?

Comment: @GoldenChris - if you found my response helpful, please accept it and upvote it. Thx.