# Install Bootstrap (on Angular,but with errors)

Tags: css, angular

Thank you all for your answers. I find the problem, it is all because i didnt get full install of angularcli.(now i fix)

Try use `npm start`, to start Angular project but `ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoa[enter image description here][1]ders":1}!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query`dead

and 
`ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query dead`
`

`In package.json (    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.4")

In code already exist bootstrap code (for example `<h3 class="bg-primary p-a-1">` cos i get this code from rep (but at work computer Angular work normally , but at home pc something goes wrong). Can you explain me why? And maybe can say how to fix it.

Thank you all for your answers. I find the problem, it is all because i didnt get full install of angularcli.(now i fix)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use bootstrap 4 in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534276/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by adding to angular.json file on the styles property:

```
"styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.scss"]
```

And on package.json file try adding: `"bootstrap": "^4.1.1",`