# How to integrate Bootstrap 4 with Angular 10?

Tags: angular

How to properly integrate Bootstrap 4, including styles and jQuery dependency in an Angular 10 project generated with Angular 10 CLI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534276/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go ,

First: `npm install bootstrap --save`

Then paste this inside `angular.json` file inside `"styles"`

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

That’s it. Run the app and you should see bootstrap 4 styles applied to the angular app

Answer (score 2):

First install `bootstrap` e.g. via `npm`

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Then include the bootstrap `css` file within the `styles` section in the `angular.json` file.

If you need modals or other bootstrap components that provide some kind of interaction handling (modals, tabs etc.) also include the according `Javascript` files within the `scripts` section.

**angular.json**

```
{
  "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/util.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/alert.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/button.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/carousel.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/collapse.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/tab.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/popover.js"
  ]
}
```

Finally when you run an `ng build --prod` all the scripts and styles are created and minified in the `dist` folder.

**dist folder**
[image: Example contents of the dist folder]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily import bootstrap inside your main styles after installing bootstrap into your project.

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Then import bootstrap into your styles.scss :

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

It's the best approach if you want to override bootstrap style or create a new theme.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) They provide nice bootstrap integration with angular. Also, there is full manual how to to to it properly.

**NOTE**: None of the above manuals are valid and should not be used in a production environment.

Here is the demo page as well: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home