# Angular 7+, How to properly include and use jquery dependent or js ui-libraries (untyped) and load/unload them

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to import jQuery dependent js libraries for a website.

**My problem is that I don't know what's the definitive or best practice to import external js libraries which do not provide a typed class with methods and properties.**

Please be informed, that I have read and tried almost all `SO` solutions and blogs except one I found here, [How to use bootstrap 4 in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534276/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-in-angular-2)

I could not understand how do I define a definition file for a library or so many libraries... Is there a better way?

**What Have I Tried So Far,**

1. I have tried including jquery and other files inside script tags doing this I run into a problem that it doesn't find the HTML in dom cause it's not rendered yet when navigating from some other component so I think I have to run the script (apart from the JS file from the template) inside the component itself and maybe also do some onLoad detection? (please advise)

> For example, I have a HomeComponent which depends on Slider Revolution
>   JS which depends on jQuery if I load other component and load the home
>   component again the slider doesn't run.. and ofcourse I don't think
>   that's the best way because I would be loading up a lot of JS
>   libraries which are not needed in that page or component and it also keeps
>   running in the memory so I have to kill every process while destroying
>   the component as well.

2. I have tried removing everything from index.html added the common ones which will be needed throughout the application like, Bootstrap JS etc. inside angular.json scripts property.

Installed jQuery typings and loading it in app component using import * as $ from 'jquery'.

The rest I import using import "file path" (which comes from a folder which I bundle using angular.json 's assets property)

// My angular.json scripts array

```
[
              "src/scripts/vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js", 
              "src/scripts/vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js",
              "src/scripts/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

//  app.component.ts import statement

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

(window as any).jQuery = (window as any).$ = $;
```

// home.component.ts (loaded inside app.component) import statements

```
import "scripts/vendor/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js";
import "scripts/vendor/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js";
import "scripts/js/revo-custom.js";
```

// inside HomeComponent's ngOnInit method I run this.scripts() method to call revolution slider

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.scripts(); // run extra UI methods for slider
  }
```

// inside scripts method I call my whole scripts that will make my slider revolution work... as given by the template but I have tried and added and removed this part as suggested by many sources

```
declare let Revolution: any;
```

// my scripts method

```
  private scripts() {

    declare let Revolution: any;

    console.log(Revolution);

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        /*==================================================================
        [ Revo1 ]*/
        var screenH1 = 0;
        var offsetArrow1 = 0;
        if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
            screenH1 = $(window).height();
            offsetArrow1 = 120;
        }
        else {
            screenH1 = $(window).height() - 70;
            offsetArrow1 = 30;
        }

        jQuery('#rev_slider_1').show().revolution();
```

**Errors:**

Angular CLI compilation error:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(63,23): error TS2339: Property 'counterUp' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
src/app/core/components/home/home.component.ts(45,5): error TS1184: Modifiers cannot appear here.
src/app/core/components/home/home.component.ts(64,40): error TS2339: Property 'revolution' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

Before moving all the imports (related to slider rev) to HomeComponent I was getting these errors in console..

```
// Error 1:


Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).show(...).revolution is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (home.component.ts:63)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3557)
    at process (jquery.js:3625)



// Error 2: 
// from some other plugin due to the same issue...

src/app/app.component.ts(64,23): error TS2339: Property 'counterUp' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
src/app/core/components/home/home.component.ts(63,40): error TS2339: Property 'revolution' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
src/app/core/components/home/home.component.ts(143,40): error TS2339: Property 'revolution' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
src/app/core/components/home/home.component.ts(219,40): error TS2339: Property 'revolution' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
src/app/core/components/home/home.component.ts(313,40): error TS2339: Property 'revolution' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
src/app/core/components/home/home.component.ts(392,40): error TS2339: Property 'revolution' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
src/app/core/components/home/home.component.ts(472,40): error TS2339: Property 'revolution' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

I think the solution we need to this is that I can't find one answer but many different ones and ones that don't work (SO and Blog Articles included)...

> My main concerns are as follows:
>
> 1. How do I use jquery without the typings as using any other library tslint gives us an error saying it's not a known property but we are
>      not using jQuery for using it's functions at this point. Some other
>      blog post referred to `declare var $: any` outside the class but it's
>      throwing an error and I have tried other way too.
> 2. How to import a JS library and manage dependency and state that this file depends on this other file in both cases when it's dependent
>      on jQuery which we have imported as typings or not and when we are
>      dependent on some other library let's say TweenMax for instance.
> 3. What's the best way to go about these DOM related UI changes which needs the DOM to be loaded like sliders as they will calculate widths
>      and stuff which cannot be done pre-render.
> 4. I am using an HTML template which is using several collected styles and scripts, how should I go about breaking it apart to the components
>      which needs particular styles or scripts or should I keep it global
>      and load once which makes it all too bulky on first load, what's the
>      best practice and how would you do it?

**Let's make this (if we can) a definitive guide to include all the information to include external JS libraries and managing dependencies globally and locally.**

P.S.  I know many people will say that it should not be done this way components should be coded and designed one by one and kept modular and jQuery and Bootstrap should not be used as their alternatives are available but in this case for this particular project.. I have the features developed and ready and I have got a prebuilt HTML theme which is designed and built with these libraries and styles, So, I have got to do it this way.

Comment: Using JQuery seems like an anti pattern, is AngularMaterial not something you could use?

Comment: Why do you need to include jQuery? @alphapilgrim is correct it is an anti-pattern. Post the problem that you are trying to solve with jQuery and I might be able to help.

Comment: Hey so, I am using a design template as mentioned above and it's using various other libraries (atleast 10 other files) which are dependent on jQuery... So, I need to know for not only this project... But in general how to load js libraries with dependencies on one another..?

and can you explain in brief how is it an anti pattern in this situation when some slider (and many other libraries) are created on top of jQuery. Is it now wrong to use jQuery at all?

Comment: Also, What about Angular Material @alphapilgrim, I already have something designed, I just want to combine my angular components (or say app) to that design..

I found an angular directive for slider revolution here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-revolution  if you want me to go the angular way but then there's other stuff that depends on jquery for which all there can't be Angular alternatives, Hence... How to deal with that?

Comment: Your question is valid in my opinion as coming from outside angular community or simply if your step by step migrating webpage, have you followed the official [guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries)?

Comment: @Lucho No, I haven't followed the doc for libraries, I guess I would need the "creating libraries" part because I don't have a published (typed) library for most of the libraries.. So, I think I will have to do that if there's no workaround for this... as I have found no  ONE single working solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Update your question with the app and home component

Comment: @Lucho I have already added that if you see.. App component just imports the jquery and makes it globally avail with window obj and home component just calls a scripts method inside ngOnInit .. I have put the scripts method up there as well.. It just has scripts for a slider for now.

Comment: What is the error you get for `declare var $: any`? Ambient declarations do work, as long as jQuery is being loaded in somewhere else, like index.html.